# Безопасный запуск программ на сервере

Tags: java, безопасность, spring-boot

Я пишу приложение, мне на сервере нужно компилировать и запускать код который пришлёт пользователь. Как мне запускать сторонний код так что бы он не мог навредить системе и не имел доступ к другим файлам на сервер.

Если есть какие-то идеи как это сделать или статьи - пишите, буду рад любой информации.

Answer (score 0):

Варианты:

- Firejail
- Docker
- AppArmor